# PyCharm: msvcrt.kbhit() and msvcrt.getch() not working?

Tags: python, pycharm, msvcrt, getch, kbhit

I've tried to read one char from the console in PyCharm (without pressing enter), but to no avail.
The functions `msvcrt.getch()` stops the code, but does not react to key presses (even enter), and `msvcrt.kbhit()` always returns 0. For example this code prints nothing:

```
import msvcrt
while 1:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        print 'reading'
print 'done'
```

I am using Windows 7, PyCharm 3.4 (the same heppens in idle).

What is wrong? Is there any other way to just read input without enter?

Comment: Same problem here. There doesn't seem to be any way to capture a keypress inside the Run console. I really hope someone address this.

Comment: Same here, `key = msvcrt.getch()` doesn't work in PyCharm 5.0.4.

Comment: I asked on intellij tracker to fix that. If you want it too you can upvote the issue in here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21240

Comment: @VitBernatik I too seem to be having the same problem. Any work arounds to this?

Answer (score 19):

It's possible in a special mode of the `Run` window.

- Check the `Emulate terminal in output console` setting checkbox in `Run/Debug Configurations`

Comment: It's still not helping.
even after I checked the emulate terminal checkbox, I still get always false in the kbhit in pycharm and true in the regular console (if I hit any key).

Comment: I know it's been a long time since this was answered, but this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare `<Class 'Bytes'>` to `<Class 'string'>`.

Cast the `key` to a `string` and then compare:

```
import msvcrt

while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        key = str(msvcrt.getch())
        if key == "b'w'":
            print(key)
```

To run the program in the **Command Line** go to: edit Configurations > Execution > enable **"Emulate terminal in output console"**.

Answer (score 0):

This code will fix. So use `key.lower()`

```
while True:
    key = msvcrt.getch()
    if key == "b'w'":
        print("Pressed: W without lower()")
        #It won't work.
    if key.lower() == "b'w'":
        print("Pressed: W with lower()")
        #This one will work.
#I don't know why but key.lower() works.
```