# PyCharm: How to debug `raw_input()` input from keyboard?

Tags: pycharm

I am using Python's [raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) to get input from keyboard.

How do I debug my code with PyCharm? I am unable to input from keyboard when (for example) `name = raw_input("Input your name")` is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You enter the input into the console that shows up, when you compile and run your script. Like so, the green text is the input.

[image]

Comment: The problem was `PyCharm->Properties->Build->Console>"Always show debug console"` which was checked, so Python console was taking my input. I de-selected the console checkbox, and now I can do what you suggest on the screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Another problem: now `key = msvcrt.getch()` doesn't work in PyCharm, but that seems to be known problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534218/msvcrt-kbhit-and-msvcrt-getch-not-working-in-pycharm.

Comment: It seems you also want to be sure to **not** check the Run Configurations option "Emulate terminal in output console, which seems odd.  You may also have problems with `getpass.getpass()`, I can only get it working in debug mode: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579468/how-to-use-the-python-getpass-getpass-in-pycharm

Answer (score 1):

For users of IntelliJ, "Always show debug console" is under IntelliJ IDEA -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Console

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found (at least for `input()`, but I guess it's the same problem) is to check `Emulate terminal in output console` in your run config. Open up your run configuration | `Modify options` dropdown | `Emulate terminal in output console`.

`Always show Debug Console` seems to have no effect on that problem for me.

You can also track and up-vote the issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42002/Not-able-to-use-input-while-debugging-with-remote-interpreter