# PyCharm: can't get input() from keyboard while debugging / stepping through

Tags: debugging, input, pycharm

I can't figure out how to input from my keyboard while debugging the program. The only place I can write something is on 'Console', but when I do, a message pop ups saying "Pause the process to use comand-line".

It's been hours, I couldn't find a solution to this. Thanks in advance.

[When running the program all works fine, I can write the input normally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NACBP.png)

[But when debugging, I get stuck when program reaches "input()" line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5sga.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm: How to debug \`raw\_input()\` input from keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603367/pycharm-how-to-debug-raw-input-input-from-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Here's link that should solve your problem. The issue is that your debugger is defaulting to the python console.

[PyCharm: How to debug `raw_input()` input from keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603367/pycharm-how-to-debug-raw-input-input-from-keyboard)