# PyCharm console during remote debug doesn't accept manual input

Tags: pycharm

[image: Pause the process to use command-line]

It tells me "Pause the process to use command-line". I cannot pause it from the IDE. I can only stop it, which does accept my input but then promptly raises "KeyboardInterrupt".

Posting as a question because I tend to stumble on SO out of habit, it probably has better SEO, and it's just nice to have interested parties. [PyCharm: can't get input() from keyboard while debugging / stepping through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35659917/866333) was never answered but I doubt it is the same issue.

I have now [found the issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42002/Not-able-to-use-input-while-debugging-with-remote-interpreter) and it's to do with my remote interpreter, which was a major influence in my decision to buy.

The code I use to trigger is:

```py
choice = int(input("Choose [0-18]: "))
```

Comment: Which PyCharm version do you use?

Comment: Good question @PavelKarateev 2021.1 Pro.

Comment: Not fixed yet, see the bug tracker [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29157/input-doesnt-work-in-console-with-remote-interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, in expectation that no fix will be forthcoming, to automate *all* the things I can replace:

```py
choice = int(input("Choose [0-18]: "))
```

with

```py
choice = 1
```

That is no trouble for one input, but not great to scale out.